# Nifi - Using jolt spec to split a column

Tags: json, text, apache-nifi, jolt

I need to transform my JSON value

```json
[
  {
    "fornecedor_frete": "EMPRESA BRAS. CORREIOS E TELEGRAFOS - OR SAO PAULO",
    "nfe_composicao": "40814-1"
  },
  {
    "fornecedor_frete": "EMPRESA BRAS. CORREIOS E TELEGRAFOS - OR SAO PAULO",
    "nfe_composicao": "40817-1"
  }
]
```

To:

```json
{
  "documentos": [
    {
      "numeroDocumento": "40814",
      "serie": "1"
    },
    {
      "numeroDocumento": "40817",
      "serie": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

There is the possibility of using jolt spec? (split before '-' and split after '-')

Thanks

Comment: what hava you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can split those values by dash within a **shift** transformation spec through use of `"*-*"` expression on the left hand side such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "nfe_*": {
          "*-*": { // split values by dash
            "#numeroDocumento": "documentos[&3].&(1,1)", // &(1,1) : going 1 level up the tree to grab the 1st asterisk
            "#serie": "documentos[&3].&(1,2)"            // &(1,2) : going 1 level up the tree to grab the 2nd asterisk
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// exchange key-value pairs
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&3[&2].@0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Another method uses **modify-overwrite** transformation spec to **`split`** such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=split('-',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@nfe_composicao[0]": "documentos[&1].numeroDocumento",
        "@nfe_composicao[1]": "documentos[&1].serie"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simpler way to achieve your desired output:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "nfe_composicao": {
          "*-*": {
            "$(0,1)": "documentos[&3].numeroDocumento",
            "$(0,2)": "documentos[&3].serie"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```