# Split string into different columns

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a JSON like:

```json
{
  "test" : "733122351/DirolWhite",
  "report_date": "2023-05-01",
  ... (other properties)
}
```

I want to split `test` and get as `id` all before `/` and all after `/` as `name`:

```json
{
  "id" : "733122351",
  "name": "/DirolWhite",
  "report_date": "2023-05-01",
  ... (other properties)
}
```

How can i achieve this? I tried with `QueryRecord` and SQL like scripts but examples for this task from PostgreSQL/Oracle/SQL Server dont work.

Comment: you can use Jolt processor. here is the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75824428/nifi-using-jolt-spec-to-split-a-column

Comment: here is another example like what you need:
https://docs.digibee.com/documentation/components/tools/transformer-jolt/transformations-with-jolt#h_18d21e23ce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @daggett already implied, you can use **JoltTransformJSON** processor in which start with a ***split*** function within a **modify** transformation  such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "test": "=split('/',@(1,&))",
      "id": "=(@(1,test[0]))",
      "name": "=concat('/',@(1,test[1]))"
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the attribute "test"
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "test": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

or you can start by using a **shift** transformation spec as another option :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "test": {
        "*/*": {
          "$(0,1)": "id", // grab the 1st asterisk replacement
          "$(0,2)": "name" // grab the 2nd asterisk replacement
            // from the wrapper level(0th)
        }
      },
      "*": "&" // replication for the other elements
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "name": "=concat('/',@(1,&))" // prefix the "name"'s value with a slash
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: What will change in code if I've multiple elements (array)? [ {...}, {...} ]

Comment: @fujidaon Then you'll need an extra wrapper starting with `"*":{` such as `{
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "test": "=split('/',@(1,&))",
        "id": "=(@(1,test[0]))",
        "name": "=concat('/',@(1,test[1]))"
      }
    }
  }`